# How to use PhotoSwipe for old versions of JavaScript by including it from a CDN?

Tags: javascript

[PhotoSwipe](https://photoswipe.com/getting-started) only shows the code for ESM modules.

```
<script type="module">
import PhotoSwipeLightbox from 'photoswipe/dist/photoswipe-lightbox.esm.js';
const lightbox = new PhotoSwipeLightbox({
  gallery: '#my-gallery',
  children: 'a',
  pswpModule: () => import('photoswipe/dist/photoswipe.esm.js')
});
lightbox.init();
</script>
```

This does not work with my current setup. I'm working in Visual Studio on a project that uses jQuery and old ways of including JS files in HTML via `<script>` tags and CDNs.

If I use `<script src='/path-to/photoswipe.esm.js'>` it apparently won't work because this file contains an `export` keyword in it and it shows an error inside console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

So, is there a way for me to use this library, but with old-school code?

Comment: Did you got any solution.?

Answer (score 3):

v5 version offer umd build, you are able to use that build to run the old way

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Gallery</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script src="./photoswipe.umd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./photoswipe-lightbox.umd.min.js"></script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../photoswipe.css">

    <div class="test-gallery">
      <a href="https://dummyimage.com/1200x600/000/fff" data-pswp-width="1200" data-pswp-height="600">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/120x60/000/fff" alt="" />
      </a>
      <a href="https://dummyimage.com/1200x1200/000/fff" data-pswp-width="1200" data-pswp-height="1200">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/60x60/000/fff" alt="" />
      </a>
      <a href="https://dummyimage.com/600x1200/000/fff" data-pswp-width="600" data-pswp-height="1200">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/30x60/000/fff" alt="" />
      </a>
    </div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var lightbox = new PhotoSwipeLightbox({
        gallery: '.test-gallery',
        children: 'a',
        // dynamic import is not supported in UMD version
        pswpModule: PhotoSwipe 
      });
      lightbox.init();
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this helps a lot... didn't notice 

Answer (score 1):

You just need to replace the links of the js files as below. Don't forget to add `type='module'` on the script tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/photoswipe@5.3.7/dist/photoswipe.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="app">
         <div class="pswp-gallery" id="my-gallery">
            <a
               href="https://cdn.photoswipe.com/photoswipe-demo-images/photos/1/img-2500.jpg"
               data-pswp-width="1875"
               data-pswp-height="2500"
               target="_blank"
               >
            <img
               src="https://cdn.photoswipe.com/photoswipe-demo-images/photos/1/img-200.jpg"
               alt=""
               />
            </a>
            <a
               href="https://cdn.photoswipe.com/photoswipe-demo-images/photos/2/img-2500.jpg"
               data-pswp-width="1669"
               data-pswp-height="2500"
               target="_blank"
               >
            <img
               src="https://cdn.photoswipe.com/photoswipe-demo-images/photos/2/img-200.jpg"
               alt=""
               />
            </a>
            <a
               href="https://cdn.photoswipe.com/photoswipe-demo-images/photos/3/img-2500.jpg"
               data-pswp-width="2500"
               data-pswp-height="1666"
               target="_blank"
               >
            <img
               src="https://cdn.photoswipe.com/photoswipe-demo-images/photos/3/img-200.jpg"
               alt=""
               />
            </a>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script type='module'>
         import PhotoSwipeLightbox from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/photoswipe@5.3.7/dist/photoswipe-lightbox.esm.js';
         const lightbox = new PhotoSwipeLightbox({
           gallery: '#my-gallery',
           children: 'a',
           pswpModule: () => import('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/photoswipe@5.3.7/dist/photoswipe.esm.js')
         });
         lightbox.init();
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```